# install TYPO3 on cloned Laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php, typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm working on a Laravel project which uses **TYPO3 8.7** for content delivery. On the TYPO3 website I only see installation guides to install TYPO3 on new projects via composer but already have a `composer.json` file in my Laravel project.

Comment: If this is blank project, without any data from TYPO3 cms, consider using Laravel based CMS or package for content. If it has data already, consider migrating this content. Also, consider about placing TYPO3 installation within subdirectory, and setting .htaccess directive and routes in Laravel to point to  TYPO3

Comment: @niklaz how do I migrate the content?

Comment: that is very specific from project to project, you need to do the research of the TYPO3 database tables, related fields, create models for Laravel, migration files that create tables, fields, migration files that do the data migration from TYPO3 to Laravel, etc. It might be better but not elegant solution to place TYPO3  within Laravel subdirectory.

Comment: @niklaz, thanks for the help, the laravel application is completely ready, models are created. What do you mean by place TYPO3 in laravel subdir?